# In PowerShell, how can I combine the results of two commands that have a 1-to-1 relashionship?

Tags: powershell

This particular example is Get-User and Get-Mailbox (Exchange 2010). Get-User returns some of the columns I need, and Get-Mailbox some others. I am having difficulty figuring out how I can combine the results of the two into a single table with the results from both.

```
Get-User -Filter "..." | Get-Mailbox -Filter "..."
```

How do I take the results of a command similar to the above and turn it into results similar to below?

```
FirstName  LastName  Alias   CustomAttribute1
---------  --------  ------  ----------------
Bob        Smith     bsmith  Example
Johnny     NoMail
Adam       Blye      ablye   Has a Mailbox
```

Note that FirstName and LastName are not returned by Get-Mailbox, and conversely Alias and CustomAttributes are not returned from Get-User. Not every user has a mailbox, so sometimes a portion of the columns would be null. But I'm having a devil of a time figuring out the best way to return a combined table like this.

Comment: I was going to suggest -pipevariable, but it doesn't seem to be supported in this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Get the users, save each user in a variable, get the mailbox for each user and then create a new object with properties from both variables

```
Get-User -Filter ... | Foreach-Object{

    $user = $_
    $mbx = Get-Mailbox $user

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        FirstName = $user.FirstName
        LastName = $user.LastName
        Alias = $mbx.Alias
        CustomAttribute1 = $mbx.CustomAttribute1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I make a custom object, which may be overkill, but it's the simplest way I've found.

Here's some sample code to play with.  Let me know if it generates any trouble or additional questions:

```
$outputCollection = @()
$users = Get-User -Filter "..."
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -Filter "..."

$users | Foreach-Object {
    #Associate objects
    $userObject = $_
    $mailboxObject = $mailboxes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $userObject.Name}

    #Make a combined object
    $outputObject = "" | Select Name, UserAttribute, MailboxAttribute
    $outputObject.Name = $userObject.Name
    $outputObject.UserAttribute = $userObject.UserAttribute
    $outputObject.MailboxAttribute = $mailboxObject.MailboxAttribute

    #Add the object to the collection
    $outputCollection += $outputObject
}

$outputCollection
```

Another option that should work is called calculated properties:

```
Get-User -Filter "..." | Select Name, UserAttribute, @{Name="OtherAttribute"; Expression={(Get-Mailbox $_.Name).MailboxAttribute}}
```

...note that this will run a new Get-Mailbox command for each entry, potentially increasing execution time

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys.  I spent a hell of a lot of time trying to figure out my own issue and your code helped me get it right.  I needed to find all the calendars were the default account was set to none.  Below is what I needed up using.

```
Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object{
    $user = $_
    $calPerms = Get-MailboxFolderPermission $user":\calendar" -User Default | Where-Object {$_.AccessRights -eq "none"}

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $user
        Permissions = $calPerms.AccessRights
        Users = $calPerms.user
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner to get FirstName, LastName, Alias and CustomAttribute1:

```
Get-User | Select Firstname, Lastname, @{Name="Alias"; Expression={(Get-Mailbox $_.Name).Alias}}, @{Name="CustomAttribute1"; Expression={(Get-Mailbox $_.Name).CustomAttribute1}}
```