# How to get a unique output with the results of two cmdlets (get-printer and get-printerport)?

Tags: powershell, printers

I need to export a list of printers to a file. It must contain values like Name,  DriverName and so on from Get-Printer, but also the value PrinterHostAddress from the cmdlet Get-PrinterPort. I think the value 'Name' from both cmdlets can be used as a key to make the union.
I've tried things like :

```
$a = get-printer
$b = get-printerport
Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru -IncludeEqual | Select Name, Comment, Location, DriverName, PrinterHostAddres
```

But it is not working.

I know, I can do it in two steps and copy/paste, but I would like to learn how to do it in one step.

Comment: The object returned from Get-Printerport doesn't have a PrinterHostAddress property?

Comment: The object returned from Get-PrinterPort does not have properties like Comment or Location. Get-Printer does not return PortNumber nor PrinterHostAddress.

Comment: See answer below

Comment: Compare-object would only work if you can pick a property that would be the same.  Btw you can pipe get-printer to get-printerport or vice versa.

Comment: This is sort of a common question, how to combine the output of two commands, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721835/in-powershell-how-can-i-combine-the-results-of-two-commands-that-have-a-1-to-1

Answer (score 0):

Iterate and select only the port objects you need:

```
$Printers = Get-Printer

$Printers | ForEach-Object {
    #Get the printer port
    $port = Get-PrinterPort | Where-Object -Property Name -like $_.PortName

    [pscustomobject]@{
        PrinterName = $_.Name
        Comment = $_.Comment
        Location = $_.Location
        Driver = $_.DriverName
        PortName = $port.Name
        IPAddress = $port.PrinterHostAddress
    }
}
```